# 'Invalid Handle object' when using a timer inside a function in MatLab

Tags: function, matlab, timer

I am using a script in MatLab that works perfectly fine by itself, but I need to make a function out of it.
The script read a .csv file, extract all values, start a timer, and at each tick displays the corresponding coordinates extracted from the .csv, resulting in a 3D animation of my graph.
What I would like is to give it the location of the .csv, so that it starts displaying the graphs for this csv.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
function handFig(fileLoc)

csv=csvread(fileLoc,1,0);  
both = csv(:,2:19);

ax=axes;
set(ax,'NextPlot','replacechildren');

Dt=0.1; %sampling period in secs

k=1;
hp1=text(both(k,1),both(k,2),both(k,3),'thumb'); %get handle to dot object
hold on;
hp2=text(both(k,4),both(k,5),both(k,6),'index');
hp3=text(both(k,7),both(k,8),both(k,9),'middle');
hp4=text(both(k,10),both(k,11),both(k,12),'ring');
hp5=text(both(k,13),both(k,14),both(k,15),'pinky');
hp6=text(both(k,16),both(k,17),both(k,18),'HAND');
L1=plot3([both(k,1),both(k,16)],[both(k,2),both(k,17)],[both(k,3),both(k,18)]);
L2=plot3([both(k,4),both(k,16)],[both(k,5),both(k,17)],[both(k,6),both(k,18)]);
L3=plot3([both(k,7),both(k,16)],[both(k,8),both(k,17)],[both(k,9),both(k,18)]);
L4=plot3([both(k,10),both(k,16)],[both(k,11),both(k,17)],[both(k,12),both(k,18)]);
L5=plot3([both(k,13),both(k,16)],[both(k,14),both(k,17)],[both(k,15),both(k,18)]);
hold off;

t1=timer('TimerFcn','k=doPlot(hp1,hp2,hp3,hp4,hp5,hp6,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,both,t1,k)','Period', Dt,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate');
start(t1);

end
```

And the doplot function used:

```
function k=doPlot(hp1,hp2,hp3,hp4,hp5,hp6,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,pos,t1,k)

k=k+1;
if k<5000%length(pos)
set(hp1,'pos',[pos(k,1),pos(k,2),pos(k,3)]);
axis([0 255 0 255 0 255]);
set(hp2,'pos',[pos(k,4),pos(k,5),pos(k,6)]);
set(hp3,'pos',[pos(k,7),pos(k,8),pos(k,9)]);
set(hp4,'pos',[pos(k,10),pos(k,11),pos(k,12)]);
set(hp5,'pos',[pos(k,13),pos(k,14),pos(k,15)]);
set(hp6,'pos',[pos(k,16),pos(k,17),pos(k,18)]);
set(L1,'XData',[pos(k,1),pos(k,16)],'YData',[pos(k,2),pos(k,17)],'ZData',[pos(k,3),pos(k,18)]);
set(L2,'XData',[pos(k,4),pos(k,16)],'YData',[pos(k,5),pos(k,17)],'ZData',[pos(k,6),pos(k,18)]);
set(L3,'XData',[pos(k,7),pos(k,16)],'YData',[pos(k,8),pos(k,17)],'ZData',[pos(k,9),pos(k,18)]);
set(L4,'XData',[pos(k,10),pos(k,16)],'YData',[pos(k,11),pos(k,17)],'ZData',[pos(k,12),pos(k,18)]);
set(L5,'XData',[pos(k,13),pos(k,16)],'YData',[pos(k,14),pos(k,17)],'ZData',[pos(k,15),pos(k,18)]);

else
k=1;
set(hp1,'pos',[pos(k,1),pos(k,2),pos(k,3)]);
axis([0 255 0 255 0 255]);
set(hp2,'pos',[pos(k,4),pos(k,5),pos(k,6)]);
set(hp3,'pos',[pos(k,7),pos(k,8),pos(k,9)]);
set(hp4,'pos',[pos(k,10),pos(k,11),pos(k,12)]);
set(hp5,'pos',[pos(k,13),pos(k,14),pos(k,15)]);
set(hp6,'pos',[pos(k,16),pos(k,17),pos(k,18)]);
end
```

However, when I run `handFig('fileName.csv')`, I obtain the same error everytime:

> ??? Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-7'
>
> Invalid handle object.

I figured that it might come from the function trying to create a new 'csv' and 'both' everytime, so I tried removing them, and feeding the function the data directly, without results.

What is exactly the problem? Is there a solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because when you call `doPlot` in the timer for the first time, you pass in `t1` as an argument, and it might not exist the first time.

Does `doPlot` need `t1` at all? I'd suggest modifying it so it's not used, and then your call to:

```
t1=timer('TimerFcn','k=doPlot(hp1,hp2,hp3,hp4,hp5,hp6,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,both,k)','Period', Dt,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate');
```

Note the missing `t1` in the `doPlot` call.

Either that, or initialise your `t1` before you create the timer so it has some value to pass in.

---

### Update (as an aside, can you use `pause(Dct)` in a loop instead? seems easier)

Actually, now I think it's a problem of scope.
It took a bit of digging to get to this, but looking at the Matlab documentation for [function callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-55506.html), it says:

> When MATLAB evaluates function handles, the same variables are in scope as when the function handle was created. (In contrast, callbacks specified as strings are evaluated in the base workspace.)

You currently give your `TimerFcn` argument as a *string*, so `k=doPlot(...)` is evaluated in the *base* workspace. If you were to go to the matlab prompt, run `handFig`, and then type `h1`, you'd get an error because `h1` is not available in the global workspace -- it's hidden inside `handFig`.

That's the problem you're running into.

However, the workaround is to specify your function as a *function handle* rather than a string (it says function handles are evaluated in the scope in which they are created, ie within `handFig`).

Function handles to `TimerFcn` have to have two arguments `obj` and `event` (see [Creating Callback Functions](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-39541.html#f9-42494)). Also, that help file says you have to put `doPlot` in its own m-file to have it not evaluate in the base Matlab workspace.

> In addition to these two required input arguments, your callback
>   function can accept application-specific arguments. To receive these
>   input arguments, you must use a cell array when specifying the name of
>   the function as the value of a callback property. For more
>   information, see Specifying the Value of Callback Function Properties.

It goes through an example of what you have to do to get this working. Something like:

```
% create timer
t = timer('Period', Dt,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate');
% attach `k` to t so it can be accessed within doPlot
set(t,'UserData',k);
% specify TimerFcn and its extra arguments:
t.TimerFcn = { @doPlot, hp1, hp2, hp3, ...., both };
start(t)
```

Note -- the reason `k` is set in `UserData` is because it needs to be somehow saved and modified between calls to `doPlot`.

Then modify your `doPlot` to have two arguments at the beginning (which aren't used), and **not accept** the k argument. To extract `k` you do `get(timer_obj,'UserData')` from within `doPlot`:

```
function k=doPlot(timer_obj, event, hp1,hp2,hp3,.....)
    k = get(timer_obj,'UserData');
    .... % rest of code here.
    % save back k so it's changed for next time!
    set(timer_obj,'UserData',k);
```

I think that's on the right track - play around with it. I'd highly recommend the mathworks forums for this sort of thing too, those people are whizzes.

[This thread](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/10567-calling-timer-function-from-within-another-function) from the mathworks forum was what got me started and might prove helpful to you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense actually, I did that, and the error changed! Always a progress ;) It now became *"??? Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-15' Undefined function or variable 'hp1'."* I don't see now, since hp1 (and the following hp) are all defined before the timer.

Comment: I worked out what it is -- it's a scope problem. When you define your callback (TimerFcn) as a string it's evaluated in the base Matlab workspace. You have to make a function handle to call `timer` from within another function. Have updated my answer.

Comment: Ooooh, here goes magic! Had trouble to make it work because I naively changed 'UserData' to 'UserTime', until I understood that 'UserData' was not a random name you chose, but an actual timer property... Anyway, thanks a lot for the fast and useful help!